# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'jest_mock_extended_1' before initialization

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, prisma

I have the following code.

singleton.ts

```
import prisma from "../prismaClient";
import { mockDeep, mockReset } from "jest-mock-extended";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { DeepMockProxy } from "jest-mock-extended/lib/cjs/Mock";

jest.mock("../prismaClient", () => ({
  __esModule: true,

  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(prismaMock);
});

export const prismaMock = prisma as unknown as DeepMockProxy<PrismaClient>;
```

prismaClient.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: [
    {
      emit: "event",
      level: "query",
    },
    {
      emit: "stdout",
      level: "error",
    },
    {
      emit: "stdout",
      level: "info",
    },
    {
      emit: "stdout",
      level: "warn",
    },
  ],
});

export default prisma;
```

I am following prisma's guide to unit testing here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing. I don't know why I keep getting this error:

**This the error message**
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'jest_mock_extended_1' before initialization

```
       7 |   __esModule: true,
       8 |
    >  9 |   default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
         |            ^
      10 | }));
      11 |
      12 | beforeEach(() => {

      at src/utils/testUtils/singleton.ts:9:12
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/testUtils/singleton.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/resolvers/functions/user.test.ts:1:1)
```

Comment: Hey, I can't seem to replicate the issue, would you be able to provide a replication? Two more things. Firstly, this is a hunch but [based on this PR](https://github.com/prisma/docs/pull/2533),  could you check out if changing the `DeepMockProxy` import helps? Secondly, if you want, I can throw up a small repo with a working unit-testing example for you to check out.

Comment: @TasinIshmam Thanks for commenting.  When you say change the `DeepMockProxy`, what would you recommend changing it to?

Comment: I meant that you could import it directly like this: `import { mockDeep, mockReset, DeepMockProxy } from 'jest-mock-extended'` using version `2.0.4` of `jest-mock-extended`.

Comment: @TasinIshmam Ah, I've just made that change. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error. I've updated the post with some more information about the error.

Comment: I see, would it be possible to create a small reproduction github repository so I could take a look?

Comment: Could you resolve it, @jmecs? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed weird to import a class that you are mocking just to export it. So i created deepMock of `PrismaClient`, added it to the `jest.mock` and exported the deepMock.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { mockDeep, mockReset, DeepMockProxy } from 'jest-mock-extended'

const prismaMock = mockDeep<PrismaClient>();

jest.mock("../prismaClient", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: prismaMock
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  mockReset(prismaMock);
});

export { prismaMock }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the import path and the path you are mocking are the same. That is `import prisma from "../prismaClient";` gets mocked by

```
jest.mock("../prismaClient", () => ({
  __esModule: true,

  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
}));
```

So this means in the file itself mocking happens which triggers that error. If you want this to work then the path you are mocking and the path you are importing here must be different. Something like the below works

```
import prisma from "../prismaClient";

jest.mock("../../prismaClient", () => ({
  __esModule: true,

  default: mockDeep<PrismaClient>(),
}));
```